# Create a Hyper-V Virtual Machine file from a Windows 2000 Server Machine

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hyper-v, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a **Windows 2008 Server Platform** with **Hyper-V** and a **Windows 2000 Professional Server** machine. I would like to know if there is an **automated** way to convert the windows 2000 to a VM and **import to Hyper-V**.

Thank you for your assistance.

John.

Comment: I will add that the license installed on that 2000, itsn't valid for the new farm if it's an OEM license (bundled with the hardware). Microsoft don't support License Transfers from OEM. I think it's a erroneous aproach, but that's how they work. To be perfectly legal u will need to buy an 2000 Server license (I think u can't, cos it's in the EOL program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/virtualmachinemanager/thread/29f946c7-07c2-4409-98fe-4e8a43fd64f9/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963740.aspx

Which physical computers can I convert :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb963740.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764232.aspx

Using SCVMM's P2V feature you can convert a windows 2000 machine to a vm.

Hope that helps